# Prevent echo JSON from going directly to screen

Tags: php, ajax, json, echo

I am able to successfully pass a JSON back via an Ajax call and put the contents in a , however the same "echo" statement returning the JSON also "echos" the JSON directly to my page, which I don't want. How do I prevent that from happening? Here is my code:

My Form:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="includes_js/registration3.js"></script>
```

Ajax:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "includes_php/registration3.php",
    data: datastring,
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(data) {
    $('.message').text(data);
        }
    })
```

PHP in the url:

```
$msgarr[] = "Please enter all Fields";
$json_msg=json_encode($msgarr);
echo $json_msg; //also sends directly to my page
```

Answer (score 1):

```
success: function(data) {
$('.message').text(data);//here is where the magic happens, 
//change that line for what you want to do
}
```

you have to parse the json: [link](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseJSON/)

```
obj=$.parseJSON(data)
```

and you can have access by their keys

```
alert(obj.key1);
```

in the php:

```
$msgarr = array("key1"=>"Please enter all Fields");
$json_msg=json_encode(utf8_encode($msgarr));
//utf8 enconde is to avoid invalid format json  for characters strangers 
echo $json_msg;
```